# Add icons to the parent rows of a DT table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt, emoticons

***The problem:***
Including an emoticon to a parent/child table mutes the child table. How to overcome this difficulty?

The added issue is that the inclusion of virtually any special character leads to the same result. I suspect that the answer is in the call back but it beats my JS skills.

***The code:***

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

### == script knicked from https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/issues/9
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(DT::DTOutput("tbl")),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        
df <- tibble(names=c("Joan", "Michael", "Vincent"), hex =c("&#129409;","&#129409;","&#129409;"), DOB=c("2020-04-05", "2020-04-05","2020-04-05"))

            df <- df %>%
                as.data.frame() %>%
                nest(-names, -hex)
            
            # add control column
            data <- df %>% {bind_cols(data_frame(' ' = rep('&#9658;',nrow(.)))
                                                  ,.)}
            
            # get dynamic info and strings
            nested_columns         <- which(sapply(data,class)=="list") %>% setNames(NULL)
            not_nested_columns     <- which(!(seq_along(data) %in% c(1,nested_columns)))
            not_nested_columns_str <- not_nested_columns %>% paste(collapse="] + '_' + d[") %>% paste0("d[",.,"]")
            
            # The callback
            # turn rows into child rows and remove from parent
            callback <- paste0("
                    table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

                    // Format data object (the nested table) into another table
                    var format = function(d) {
                      if(d != null){
                        var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str," + '\">').replace('.','_') + '<thead><tr>'
                        for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                          result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
                        }
                        result += '</tr></thead></table>'
                        return result
                      }else{
                        return '';
                      }
                    }

                    var format_datatable = function(d) {
                      var dataset = [];
                      for (i = 0; i < + d[",nested_columns,"]['DOB'].length; i++) {
                        var datarow = [];
                        for (var col in d[",nested_columns,"]){
                          datarow.push(d[",nested_columns,"][col][i])
                        }
                        dataset.push(datarow)
                      }
                      var subtable = $(('table#child_' + ",not_nested_columns_str,").replace('.','_')).DataTable({
                        'data': dataset,
                        'autoWidth': false,
                        'deferRender': true,
                        'info': false,
                        'lengthChange': false,
                        'ordering': true,
                        'paging': false,
                        'scrollX': false,
                        'scrollY': false,
                        'searching': false
                      });
                    };

                    table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                      var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                      if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        row.child.hide();
                        td.html('&#9658;');
                      } else {
                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                        td.html('&#9660;');
                        format_datatable(row.data())
                      }
                    });
                           
                           "
            )
            
            
            DDT <-  datatable(
                data,
                escape = -c(2,4), # raw HTML in column 2
                options = list( paging=FALSE,info = FALSE,
                                columnDefs = list(
                                    list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,nested_columns) ), # Hide row numbers and nested columns
                                    list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1) # turn first column into control column
                                )
                ),
                callback = JS(callback)
            )
            
    
        
        output$tbl <- DT::renderDT({
            DDT
            
        }, server = FALSE, width = 6)
        
        session$onSessionEnded(function() {
            observe(cat(paste0("Ended: ", values$sessionId)))
        })
        
        if(format(Sys.time(), "%M")=='00'){
            onStop(function() {
                dbDisconnect(con)
            })
        }
        
        # you need set the server to FALSE
    },
    options = list(port = 33333)
)
```

[image: pretty but empty]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a datatable with children, it's better to use [the method I give on my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html). Currently there are some mistakes in the callback code, I need to update this post, so I provide the full code here for your case:

```
library(DT)

NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}


Dat <- NestedData(
  data.frame(
    names = c("Joan", "Michael", "Vincent"), 
    hex = c("&#129409;","&#129409;","&#129409;"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ),
  children = list(
    data.frame(DOB = "2020-04-05", stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    data.frame(DOB = "2020-04-05", stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    data.frame(DOB = "2020-04-05", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  )
)


## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  var options = {",
  "    'dom': 't',",
  "    'data': data,",
  "    'columns': columns,",
  "    'autoWidth': true,",
  "    'deferRender': true,",
  "    'info': false,",
  "    'lengthChange': false,",
  "    'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "    'order': [],",
  "    'paging': false,",
  "    'scrollX': false,",
  "    'scrollY': false,",
  "    'searching': true,",
  "    'sortClasses': false,",
  "    'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "    'headerCallback': headerCallback",
  "  };",
  "  var hasChild = colNames.indexOf('_details') > -1",
  "  if(!hasChild){",
  "    var columnDefs = ",
  "      {'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]};",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable(",
  "      $.extend(options, columnDefs)",
  "    );",
  "  } else {",
  "    var columnDefs = {",
  "      'columnDefs': [",
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},",
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]};",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable(",
  "      $.extend(options, columnDefs)",
  "    ).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -c(colIdx+1, 3),
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!!! Je te dois une grande bière bien fraîche

Comment: @UlysseColonna ;-) Glad to help. Please do not forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)